# replace value with in " " with null value and need to obtain string after " "

Tags: java, substitution

i have n number of strings like this :

```
"AC_def" 123 dffgg fdffv ,
"av bgg" 1234 frfvf gfg , 
"av cvc bgg" 1234 frfvf gfg.
```

i need to replace the value with in quotes with null value and need only string after that.
How should i do this using substring.

Comment: Can you clarify what output you need (the actual string you expect)?

Answer (score 0):

I **guess** this is what you want. If it's not, please provide more details as assylias said!

```
    String data = "\"AC_def\" 123 dffgg fdffv ,";
    System.out.println(data);
    data = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf("\"") + 1);
    System.out.println(data);
```

Anyway... since I am waiting for the proof...

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // input by user...
    //"AC_def" 123 dffgg fdffv ,
    String data = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(data);
    data = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf("\"") + 1);
    System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: well... you're right about not changing input, but it's either input from a file or scanner object. I don't think I am changing it because that's what it is supposed to be like in Java String. Prove me wrong by providing what else it should be, please!

Comment: i have got the answer by msam

Answer (score 0):

as a start:

`String str2 = str1.replaceFirst("\\\".*\\\"", "");`

Edit:
if they are in an array you can always loop:

```
for (int i = 0;i< strarray.length;i++)
{
  strarray[i] = strarray[i].replaceFirst("\\\".*\\\"", "");
}
```

Note that you will still be creating new String instances

Comment: Output : a substring not having value with in quotes.
example 123 dffgg fdffv

Comment: If you have a third quote this will elminate it - "abc " def " ghi -> ghi. If you want to keep a third quote modify the regular expression as needed (eg: "\\\"[^\"]*\\\""). It will also keep any characters before the quote abc "def" ghi -> abc  ghi. Since we don't know the exact requirements we can only give hints and guesses

Comment: hey im done !!thanks
this method help me out
String str2 = str1.replaceFirst("\\\".*\\\"", "");

Comment: In case if i need to obtain value within quotes , can i use this method :
String temprecord = text[i].substring((text.indexOf("\"")),text.lastindexOf("\"");

???

Comment: If you mean: String temprecord = text[i].substring(text[i].indexOf("\""),text[i].lastindexOf("\"")) , yes, as long as you want any text between the first and last " - in the case of a third quote, it will be included in your result

Comment: oks..that is working for me...
In case if i need value within quotes & before a space
"afr_nd nd"
i require : afr_nd 

also i have below strings in an array :
fault asg_fg dfghhnh,
fault asf dfgh

and i need the part after fault asg_fg
and all such strings are variable , but in every case i need  value after (fault asg_fg or fault asg or fault asgdd )till end...

Comment: at this point I would suggest you read a little bit about regular expressions. hint: you can easily modify the initial expression to include an optional (or compulsory) 'fault' and space or whatever else you need

Comment: actually im using indexof and substring in my programm and i have more than 10,000 varying strings ...so m almost stuck here and no hope yet...a guidance will be helpful

Comment: you can pass a String to indexof. Is this a homework assignment? Try to find a pattern or patterns in all the strings, divide your problem to make it as simple possible, after you have an initial, possibly raw, working solution you can then try to improve on it.

Comment: i have string in below pattern , for example : 
fault abhywe tytuytu uiuiuu uouuo
fault abhywe_po eygdyed udded uude hih
and i need : string.substring(string.indexOf("fault")+6),(string.?? );

here ?? im unknown how to proceed so that i can get value like 'tytuytu uiuiuu uouuo' ..